# Update a data.frame within an sapply function

Tags: r, dataframe, sapply

Probably a simple question.

I'm running an `sapply` function in which I'd like to update a `data.frame` in addition to other operations the function does.

I thought this example code would work:

```
df <- NULL
res <- sapply(1:10, function(i){
  if(is.null(df)){
    df <- data.frame(itr=i,let = letters[i])
  } else{
    tmp.df <- data.frame(itr=i,let = letters[i])
    df <- rbind(df,tmp.df)
  }
  return(i)
})
```

In reality I return something more elaborate than just a index `i`. This is just a simplified example.

But `df` remains NULL after running the `sapply`.

How do I get `df` updated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `df` defined in the function that is being assigned to is not the same `df` as the `df` defined outside the function.  If you replace both occurrences of `df <-` with `df <<-` then it will work.

Although inefficient (because successively appending to an object in R is inefficient) you can successively append rows in a loop like this:

```
df <- NULL 
for(i in 1:10) df <- rbind(df, data.frame(itr = i, let = letters[i]))
```

Better would be to create a list of rows and then `rbind` them at once:

```
do.call("rbind", lapply(1:10, function(i) data.frame(itr = i, let = letters[i])))
```